# FileSystemStorage isDirectory returns false for a directory

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to write a file browser in CN1 to let the user select a profile picture for upload.
I tried using the FileSystemStorage's isDirectory() method, but it is returning false for a directory.

Code:

```
 private void displayFiles(final Container c, String root)
{
    c.removeAll();
    FileSystemStorage fs = FileSystemStorage.getInstance();
    try {
        String files[] = fs.listFiles(root);
        for(final String file: files)
        {

            System.out.println(file+"-->"+fs.isDirectory(file));
            if(fs.isDirectory(file))
            {
                Button b = new Button("Folder::"+file);
                b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
                        displayFiles(c, file);
                    }
                });
                c.addComponent(b);
            }else
            {
                Container c1 = new Container(new BoxLayout(BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
                Label l = new Label("File::"+file);
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                c1.addComponent(l);
                c1.addComponent(cb);
                c.addComponent(c1);
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException ex) {

    }
    c.revalidate();
}
```

Output:
CN1Log__$-->false

CN1Preferences-->false

Cookies-->false

data-->false

FaceBookAccesstmp652635968-->false

folder1-->false

folder2-->false

HELLOCN1FS-->false

myFileName-->false

token-->false

Screenshot of the emulator:

[image]

Screenshot of the explorer

[image]

The behavior is same on the phone as well

Could this be a bug ?

Is there something that I am not doing correctly ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the full path for the file:

```
if(fs.isDirectory(root + file))
```

Comment: Thanks Shai. Not sure how i missed this. Its anyways: fs.isDirectory(root+FileSystemStorage.getInstance().getFileSystemSeparator()+file